# Statusbar plugin color change not working on android // org.apache.cordova.statusbar

Tags: html, cordova, android-layout, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I wanted to add the statusbar plugin, so I can change the android's statusbar color. The only problem is: it doesnt work. I've tried several things, but it still don't work.
This is my HTML, as you can see I tried several things.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function color() {
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#ECF0F1");
}
function colorc() {
if (StatusBar.isVisible) {
document.getElementById("p").style.color = "green";
}
else {
document.getElementById("p").style.color = "red";
}
}
function changer() {
document.getElementById("p").style.color = "pink";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="color();">
<p id="p">hi</p>
<button onclick="StatusBar.hide();">hide</button>
<button onclick="StatusBar.show();">show</button>
<button onclick="color();">color</button>
<button onclick="colorc();">color check</button>
<button onclick="changer();">hi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my config

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.not.working.bar" 
version="1.0.0">
<name>Statusbar</name>
<description></description>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.4" 
source="pgb"/> 
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ECF0F1" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0"/>
<preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
<preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21"/>
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
<access origin="*"/>
</widget>
```

The only thing that doesn't work is the color. I can hide/show the bar, check if it's showing or hiding, but I can't manage to change the color. PLEASE HELP

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use version 1.0+ of the StatusBar plugin, like this: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar`. You can check the version by `cordova plugin ls`.

When you add the StatusBar plugin as `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar` then you get v0.1.10. You can see [in this file@0.1.10](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/r0.1.10/src/android/StatusBar.java%22in%20this%20file%22) that none of the color methods are implemented on Android. On the other hand [@1.0.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/r1.0.0/src/android/StatusBar.java) the backgroundColorByHexString is implemented.